# Update Textview right after user change settings value

Tags: java, android, user-controls, application-settings, preferenceactivity

In my app I let the user choose a name to display. It should display as:
Hello `usertext`!

I can successfully update settings. I used PreferenceActivity.
I can change the value too. But to change the text in the selected textview, I have to restart the app.

How can I update my textview right after users update the value in settings?

Comment: please display the code you're using so far

Comment: You can use `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`

Comment: @BR89 my code is very similar to below LBJ33's code.

Comment: @ahmad aghazadeh how do i do that exactly?please could you show me some example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener changeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Code goes here            
        return true;
    }
};

EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref1));
pref1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);

EditTextPreference pref2 = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref2));
pref2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences for this, don't forget to use .apply after setting the values though. Here is an example(Don't forget to change the values to match your editText, buttons, classes, ect):

Activity Two(Where they enter the new value and save it):

```
public class settings extends  MainActivity {
private Button mButton;
private EditText mEditText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtUsername);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            if (mEditText.getText().length() > 0) {
                editor.putString("username", mEditText.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();

            } else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid username.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Activity One(Where you want to view the username):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTxtUsername;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTxtUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    String username = pref.getString("username", "");

    mTxtUsername.setText(username);
    }
}
```

This should work, and will save the value for next time they open the app as well!
Let me know if you have any problems with the code, I just whipped it up fast

Comment: thanks.exactly that was i did.but the problem i have is value in that textview is not updated until i close and re-open my app.i need to find a way to update textview right after i update the value in settings.thanks for the help @LBJ33

Comment: LBJ33 it worked!thanks 

Although I found putting this line before setContentView() line in onCreate() method is working too,only if i stated default value inside my preferences xml file.

PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

Thanks for the answer.it works as i expected